# What's the purpose of claims-based authorization?

Tags: wcf, authorization

I've been reading about Azure's Access Control Service and claims-based authorization in general for a while now, and for whatever reason, I still don't see the rationale behind moving from role/permission-based authorization to a claims-based model. The models seem similar to me (and they probably are), except that the list of what the client can and can't do comes from a third party and is wrapped up in some sort of token, instead of from some sort of database that the server has to query. What's the advantage of getting a third party (the token issuer) involved?

I fully understand the advantages of outsourcing authentication to a third party. It allows apps to not have to create new users all the time, worry about storing passwords, etc. when they can just push that off to some other service that already has the infrastructure set up. It's essentially the DRY principle for authentication.

However, in my mind, that same logic doesn't work for authorization. Each app has its own resources it has to protect, and therefore its own rules for authorizing users to perform certain actions. The infrastructure seems simple enough that each app could create it on its own (a table mapping users to roles, and possibly another mapping roles to permissions), and even if you wanted to outsource it, it seems that the claims-based model is doing something more complicated than that.

The only partial explanation I've seen comes from [Building a Claims-Based Security Model in WCF](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ClaimsBasedSecurityModel), and it gives two main advantages to claims-based auth: more flexibility, and someone to "vouch" that the information in a claim is correct. When would you need either of those?

Claims-based authorization seems to be gaining popularity, so I assume there must be some good rationale for it; I just haven't figured out what that is yet. Can someone please provide a concrete example of a situation where claims-based auth works better than role-based, and why it works better in that case?

(EDIT: I missed a third benefit listed in the article: supporting single sign-on/federation. But doesn't authentication deal with that on its own without getting authorization involved?)

Answer (score 9):

I guess the main promise of a benefit from federated security / claims-based system would be one fewer area you have to deal with different systems.

Imagine a site where you have local users authenticating with Windows credentials, a bunch of internet users using username/password, others using certificates, and maybe another group of users with biometric authentication.

In today's system, you have to set up and deal with all different kinds of authentication schemes and their different ways of doing things. That can get pretty messy.

The promise of a federated security solution would be to handle all those chores for you - the STS (security token server) would handle all different kinds of authentication systems for you, and present to you a uniform and trusted set of claims about a caller - no matter from where and on which path he's arriving at your site.

Of course, just examining and reacting to a single set of claims rather than having to understand four, five, ten different and disparate authentication systems looks like a really compelling promise to me!

Comment: Right, but to me, that all sounds like authentication rather than authorization. I guess I'm imagining that the user gives you some token that has their authenticated ID, and the server looks up permissions based on that ID. The token could contain other claims, but I don't understand why it would.

I'm looking at this mostly from the perspective of Azure's ACS, which doesn't really seem to give you these benefits, since it only accepts a couple of types of authentication. Am I wrong in viewing ACS as a pure authorization provider (no authentication) and not seeing much value in that?

Comment: Yes, true - but since you're presented with a uniform set of claims after authentication, you can also simplify your authorization on it. You don't need to deal with different kinds of "identities" being presented to you - you just get a set of claims, and based on that, you authorize (or deny) a given caller to do somethnig

Comment: I haven't invested enough time in Azure ACS to answer those detail questions, sorry

Comment: Thanks, that's starting to make sense, now. I'm still a little hazy on ACS, but I think I'm at least starting to see the rationale behind claims-based auth in general, now.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of claims based authorization is to allow fine grained access control based on Boolean expressions that evaluate characteristics of the accessing entity and the resource.  This reduces or eliminates the need to provision groups.  As with federated identity, claims also provide a vehicle for an Identity provider to manage their users wile allowing a resource provider to gate users access to assets.

Note:  Claims can be used within a single enterprise and provide the following benefits:

1) Access grants and revocations do not require provisioning or de-provisioning

2) Thus changes are instantaneous

3) Resource owners can define the scope and requirements for access rather than having admins create groups  manage group memberships - this moves the access control decisions into the hands of the folks best suited to make such decisions (the data owner)

4) This results in fewer groups being required and fewer member in the groups

5) There can be issues creating a single group to accommodate a large community having access (for 
example all full time employees can read a HR policy) - Claims avoids this problem

6) Audit is more informative - the reason a grant or deny took place is clearly visible

7) Claims support dynamic attributes, such as 2-factor authentication, time of day, or network restrictions

There are a lot more reasons, but those ones come to mind.  There will shortly be a video at www.cionsystems.com that showcases this (disclaimer - I work there and recorded the video - I still need to post it) Also, for reference, claims aware apps and platforms include SharePoint 2010 on, Windows 2012 (file shares), Azure, many SaaS services (Facebook and Salesforce)

Also, with claims you can blend information from multiple sources (say Facebook and your local AD) etc. - which is increasingly important

Not sure if the rules allow this, but feel free to ping me with your questions or comments.  I'll happily edit the post to make any corrections or add pertinent info.

Claims can come from AD, databases tables, SAML, OAuth, algorithms, XACML  or any other trusted provider.  Harnessing claims requires a bit of kit - with apps and platforms evolving rapidly in this space.

All the Best,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Claims-based access control also helps build up attribute-based access control and policy-based access control. If you standardize on a set of pre-agreed claims that can be assigned to users based on their other attributes (e.g. a US manager can have claim U_M; a European manager can have claim E_M).
In an attribute-based and policy-based environment, it's possible to achieve fine-grained authorization (also known as fine-grained entitlements) using XACML.
In this case, you can have authorization that depends on who the user is (claims) but also what they want to do (resource information) and under which circumstances (context).

CBAC with XACML will let you express rules like:

> managers can edit notes they created themselves or notes that their
>   direct reports created.

Answer (score 0):

Role based security is a limited security model 
Authorization is:

```
 Based on role membership only
```

Claims based security is much more flexible and expressive
Authorisation  can be:

- Based on role membership

  Based on Age

  Based on Geographic Location

  Based on an account balance

  Based on a size

  Based on pre-defined securtiy levels

  Based on any combination of the above